# Python Code get token (battle net api)

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, python-2.7, oauth-2.0

I  am new to web devloping and now I want to import the api into myweb but there is something wrong. need help

this is my code and I am running on GAE

I get
`IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <gae_override.httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0xfbe4d8a0>)`

The official guide is here https://dev.battle.net/docs

I wondered what's wrong with my code

```
import webapp2
import oauth2
from uuid import uuid4
import urllib

CLIENT_ID = "myid"
CLIENT_SECRET = "mysecret"
REDIRECT_URI = "https://sciisirius.appspot.com/test"

def make_authorization_url():

 state = str(uuid4())
 params = {"client_id": CLIENT_ID,
          "response_type": "code",
          "state": state,
         "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI,
 }

 url = "https://kr.battle.net/oauth/authorize?" + urllib.urlencode(params)
 return url

class test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
   code = self.request.get("code")
   if code:
       f = urllib.urlopen("https://kr.battle.net/oauth/token", urllib.urlencode(params))
       self.response.write(f.read())
   else:
       self.redirect(make_authorization_url()) 
       params = { "code": code,
                 "grant_type": "authorization_code",
                "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI
       }

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
 ('/test',test)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: The CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET that you are using, did they come from GAE or Battle.net?

Comment: They are from Battle net

Comment: what happens if you go to the full URL in your browser?

Comment: <oauth>
<error_description>
An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>

Comment: First, I'd try using an OAuth2 debugging tool such as this one from Runscope - https://www.runscope.com/oauth2_tool - just double check that you can, indeed, get an auth code and access token with your credentials.